# Does is_file() use include paths?

Tags: php

If I add a path to the include_path, will the php function: is_file() then use this path to search for a filename that I pass to it?

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8461352/362536  As well as http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php

Comment: Did you try it? What did it do?

Answer (score 2):

No. It only checks the passed absolute or relative path, it doesn't respect include paths

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php), it doesn't look like it.

Looks like if you don't include the path, it uses the current directory, otherwise it will use the path you provide.